# Reinsert a deleted record back at the same Id

Tags: sql-server

Reinsert a deleted record back at the same Id while id is a Primary key.
Sample code below.

```
Select * from tblTest where Id=1
delete from tblTest where Id=1
Insert INto tblTest
  values ('x','y') but in the place of Id= 1
```

The issue is:

1. The table now start as Id= 2 when I do a (`Select * from tblTest`)
2. I can't reseed Identity
3. I don't want to restore the .db just for 1 record.

Comment: [SET IDENTITY INSERT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you're worried about the value of the `IDENTITY` column, then `IDENTITY` is the wrong choice. It's by design that an `IDENTITY`'s value isn't reused if a row is deleted. A `IDENTITY`'s value of designed to be nothing more than an arbitrary, always ascending number; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @DaleK That did the trick. :-) Thank you

Comment: @Larnu I totally agree with you. But my issue was I didn't want the table Id value to start 2 it was bothering me. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @DaleK yes! totally did! :-)